# Cron Jobs in Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, cron, magento-1, php-5.4

I have created cron jobs @ every 1 min to run. And I run the http://localhost/magento/cron.php. but it's not working.

**My Code is:**

**Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Easylife_CJobs_Model_Observer {
    public function setStatus() {
        Mage::log("Cron Jobs Working Fine!",null,"cronjobs");
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_CJobs>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Easylife_CJobs>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cjobs>
                <class>Easylife_CJobs_Model</class>
            </cjobs>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <cjobs>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>Easylife_CJobs_Model_Observer::setStatus</model>
                </run>
            </cjobs>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Please let me know is this procedure is correct else is another procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model node should contain the model reference `<model>cjobs/observer::setStatus</model>` instead of a full class name.

Also make sure logging is turned on or put `true` as fourth argument to `Mage::log()` in order to force writing the `"Cron Jobs Working Fine!"` log.

Comment: **Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Easylife\CJobs\Model\Easylife\CJobs\Model\Observer.php'** Error is Came.

Comment: I have modified config.xml file. now working fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is also look at `cron_schedule` table if you debug cron. If you did it you could understand that the problem is following:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid model/method definition, expecting "model/class::method".' in /var/www/local.dev/www/mg18com/app/Mage.php:595